# The set of primes that split $x^2-5$ is $\{p:p \equiv \pm1 \mod 5\}$.

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

My professor worked this out in class and I am lost on how he did it. The definition I am using for split is, for a polynomial $f$ with degree d, with integer coefficients, a prime is $f$-split if $f\mod p$ has $d$ distinct roots.

What I want is to prove (understand the proof of) the set of primes that split $x^2-5$ is $\{p:p \equiv \pm1 \mod 5\}$.

A rough out line of the proof he did is, he stated there is a field $E$ that contains $F_{p}$ and $c \in E$ such that $\Phi_{5}(c) = 0$ Let $b = c+c^{-1}$. $\Phi_{5}(x)$ is the cyclotomic polynomial. with some manipulation he ended up with the desired congruency, yet I don't see the how he knew the choice of $b$ or even fully understand the proof. I added a photo of the given proof.

[Actual photo of professors proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6P7AV.png)

Comment: The polynomial splits modulo $2$ and modulo $5$ as well.

Comment: Why? That seems to contradict the answer below.

Comment: I misread. The polynomial splits into linear factors, but doesn't have two distinct roots (modulo $2$ it has $1$ as a root twice, and modulo $5$ it has the root $0$ twice).

Comment: @JayV: My answer is for *odd* primes. If $p=2$, $5\equiv 1\mod 2$, so $x^2-5=x^2-1$ (in $\mathbf Z/2\mathbf Z[x]) $=(x-1)^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assertion results, for odd primes, from the law of quadratic reciprocity, which says in this case that $5$ is a square $\bmod p$ if and only if $p$ is a square $\bmod 5$. Now the only non-zero squares $\bmod 5$  are $1$ and $-1$.

Comment: That is a lot easier way to think about it. Thank you.